# Is it possible to delete specific commits from forked repo by github website

Tags: github

I searched this but unable to find my answer.
And I just want to know the non command line way to do this....
Or is there any other way to achieve this same ?

Comment: Using a desktop tool doesn't always mean command line. You can use SourceTree, TortoiseGit, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [delete files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14237674/6309) (from a repo you own, like a fork)

But you cannot directly from the web interface delete commits.
For that you would need to clone, do an interactive rebase (dropping the commits you don't want) and `git push --force`.
Even a [revert does not seem possible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35300297/6309).

The OP adds:

> Actually I have 3 branches one is `master` and rest two are `patch-1` and `patch-2` and I messed up with `master` branch before creating `patch-1` and `patch-2` branches so some useless commits are also cloned from `master` to `patch-1` and `patch-2` branch so please can you help me to delete those commits which are cloned from `master`?

No without cloning the repo though:

```
git clone /url/of/your/fork
cd yourfork
git remote add upstream /url/original/repo
git fetch upstream

git checkout -b patch-1 origin/patch-1
git checkout -b patch-2 origin/patch-2
```

Then replay your patches on top of upstream `master`:

```
git rebase --onto upstream/master master patch-1
git rebase --onto upstream/master master patch-2
```

Finally reset `master` to the upstream `master` branch:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard upstream/master
```

And then push everything back to your fork:

```
git push --force --mirror
```

Comment: Actually I have 3 branches one is master and rest two are patch-1 and patch-2 and I messed up with master branch before creating patch-1 and patch-2 branches so some useless commits are also cloned from master to patch-1 and patch-2 branch so please can you help me to delete those commits which are cloned from master

Comment: Actually I m new to github and I cloned repo as you suggested but now I m confused how to delete commits ... You have any reference link for my situation or you can guide me ?

Comment: @Golu I have updated the answer to include the precise steps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help But I have one doubt and I want to clear by doubt before implementing your steps .I gave a pull request from patch-1 branch to original repo/master or project so, my doubt = is your steps will affect my PR (PR is still not merged)

Comment: @Golu The final push --force will override the remote patch-x branch, and will automatically update your PR. Except that updated existing PR  won't have the extra commits from your old master, that you don't want.

Comment: Thnx but I am stuck at your 5th command which is for rebase error is fatal: no such branch/commit 'patch-2'

Comment: Do you have a patch-2 branch?

Comment: I mean, obviously replace those names with the accueil name of your patch branches

Comment: Or checkout them first: Git checkout -b patch-2 origin/patch-2

Comment: Yes I am trying with my original branch names which is Hax4us-patch-1 and Hax4us-patch-2 ..... But not working same error of no such branch

Comment: Can you please add this additional command in your answer in appropriate location

Comment: I have in my previous comment

Comment: git checkout -b my branch_name origin/mybranch_name   r8 ?

Comment: @Golu Great. I have edited the answer to add the missing command: that might be helpful to others as well.